# How to plot elements in the matrix on the graph? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I have just started MATLAB. So please help me.

If I have a m*n matrix.

I want to plot a 3-d plot with x-axis and y- axis as x indices and y indices respectively. And on the z axis, element at i,j in the matrix.

How to plot it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your m*n matrix is `A`

You can plot the data as a [surface](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html?refresh=true) by calling

```
figure %# opens a new figure, otherwise you'll overwrite an existing one
surf(A)
```

If you want to add x- and y- indices

```
surf(xIndices, yIndices, A)
```

If you want a scatter plot, you need to create arrays of the same size as A for the coordinates first

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(xIndices, yIndices);
plot3(xx(:), yy(:), A(:), 'o');

or

scatter3(xx(:), yy(:), A(:))
```

Comment: Or [mesh()](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html).. I think that would cover all options...